# Wordpress equivalent of "menu" in Magento

Tags: wordpress, magento

The wordrpess's menu feature allows "categories" & "pages" to be added to a menu. Is there something similar in Magento ?

In other words, I am looking to be able to group different categories together in order to display them in different menus.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not exist natively - it's a notoriously absent facility in the app. Many people end up rewriting or extending the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` class and *catalog/navigation/top.phtml* template to suit the logic and markup to their needs.

Comment: Hmm. That sucks. I've been looking for a plugin that could expose an api and management of category groups but have still found nothing.